# robocopy /b access denied

Tags: backup, permission-denied, access-denied, robocopy

I'm going nuts over Robocopy. I want to create a 1:1 exact copy (including data, and permissions of each file & folder) of two local volumes.  Actually, they are located on different physical HDD's. Say I have `A:\` and `B:\`.  I just want to copy all of the stuff from `A:\` to `B:\`.

So, I tried this command:

`robocopy A:\ B:\ /e /b /copyall /dcopy:T`

But I keep getting access denied errors.  Same results with `/zb` switch.  I am using elevated/admin privileges in Win7 to run the Robocopy commands in command prompt.

I found a Microsoft hotfix, which fails to install on my machine, not sure if it would remedy my problem (KB979808).

I don't know if the problem is the commands, Robocopy itself, or the operating system.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, right-clickind and running the command as Administrator doesn't work, but if you go into safe mode, the command works fine - you have admin rights.